# How to print name under the column that has the max value? (pandas) (python)

Tags: python, pandas

The data sheet I am working with is organized with the columns: 'Country', 'Internet Users', and 'Population'. I am able to work out and print the max percentage of population using internet, but how do I print the name of the country with that max percentage. For example, Indonesia will have the max with 94% but I am only able to print "94%". I want to print "Indonesia 94%".

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pop = pd.read_csv('country_internet.csv')
op = input("Enter output file name: ")

pop['Percentage'] = round(pop['Internet users']/pop['Population']*100,2)
pop.plot(x = 'Country', y = 'Percentage')

print("Maximum percentage of all countries:",pop['Percentage'].max(),"%")

plt.show()
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.savefig(op)
```

Comment: You could try `row = pop.iloc[pop['Percentage'].idxmax()]
print(row['Country'])` etc.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
# To get the country with max percentage
condition = pop.loc[pop['Percentage'] == pop['Percentage'].max(), 'Country']

print('Country with max percentage is: {} {:.0%}'.format(condition, pop['Percentage'].max()))
```

Output:

```
'Country with max percentage is: Indonesia 94%'
```

Comment: Looks good! They did want the country AND the percentage though, so maybe edit your answer to add in the percentage too. Formatted with `:.0%` as well, of course. :)